# Unable to instantiate Action, com.hcl.hips.action.KAListproduct, defined for 'KAListproduct' in namespace '/'com.hcl.hips.action.KAListproduct

Tags: java, struts

```
Unable to instantiate Action, com.hcl.hips.action.KAListproduct,  defined for 'KAListproduct' in namespace '/'com.hcl.hips.action.KAListproduct
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:306)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:387)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:186)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:61)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:458)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at net.sf.j2ep.ProxyFilter.doFilter(ProxyFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.hcl.hips.action.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:574)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1527)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hcl.hips.action.KAListproduct
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:146)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.getClassInstance(ObjectFactory.java:96)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.getClassInstance(SpringObjectFactory.java:206)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:128)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:139)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildAction(ObjectFactory.java:109)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:287)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: Please provide more information, otherwise your question will not be answered.

Answer (score 0):

your error is described in the stack trace

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hcl.hips.action.KAListproduct
```

You did not import your class, or somehow failed to wire up it up correctly.  Post relevant configs if you want further help.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this is the code to resolve this issue

http://www.bpjava.net/Struts2_Configuration_Plugin/config-browser/showBeans.action

i do not know whether kiran kumar solved it or not...

But for future people........